# MySQL - Innodb, search

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I recently switched from myisam to innodb in one of my mysql tables. Before i was using MATCH(). Since innodb doesn't support match() i decided to use LIKE.

Now I have a problem. My table is 190,6 MiB big and have 234,083 rows. When I use LIKE my server goes slow.

I switched to innodb from myisam to stop locking the table.

What am I gonna do? Thanks!

Comment: Install and use a real seach engine like Lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, MyISAM tables don't fare too well on write-heavy situations.  InnoDB are better there; but don't have full-text indexes (to use `match()`).  That boils down to a few answers:

- you can have the write-heavy table(s) on InnoDB and the full-text one (should be just one or two) on MyISAM
- if they're the same; or if several tables have big texts, then factor those texts out to a single (MyISAM) table with just the text and key fields to JOIN to any other table(s).
- if the texts themselves are the ones with heavy writes, bite the bullet and use a dedicated text search engine (Sphinx, Lucene, etc)

Comment: Thats a great idea. I am creating a MyISAM table and put the big texts in there and join. Awesome, huge thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question I'm dealing with as well. Someone pointed me to the [Sphinx engine](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#about).

Here's a post about the performance on the [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,98685,98685)

It hasn't been pressing so far, so I haven't tested it out yet. If you go this route, please let me know your findings on the performance.